# mod_rewrite to correct directory rather than root directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to use mod_rewrite to redirect

http://www.site.com/new_cars/cars.php?make=brandname

to have a friendlier url of
http://www.site.com/new_cars/brandname.html

I've tried

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /new_cars/cars.php?make=$1 [L]`

but this redirects to the root rather than the /new_cars/ direcory.

Can anyone explain how to resolve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `PT` (pass-through) flag to your `RewriteRule`.  Read more in the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt).

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /new_cars/cars.php?make=$1 [L,PT]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was missing